# When is Dishonored over?

Tags: dishonored

I've made it to the top of the Lighthouse, I have found Emily and killed her captor, now what? Emily is standing at the edge and is non-responsive to me. Is the game over?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. The game should cut to the ending.
I would suggest reloading your last checkpoint. and attempting to rescue Emily again

Answer (score 6):

Bugs are quite frequent in Dishonored and are sometimes randomly triggered or occur when certain conditions are not met. The only real solution is reloading your last save. Remember to save often!

Comment: Not just often, but in different slots. Overwriting a stable save with a bugged one is a recipe for broken monitors.

Comment: You're right. I should have clarified separate saves.